# Fix pasted text from PDF credit statement

Tags: excel, vba, date, pdf, text

I have this text file that I copied from a credit card statement

Sample line 1:

```
August 18       August 18       Balance Conversion      :02/06          4,671.30
```

Sample line 2:

```
August 1        August 2        *Php-Anytiefit-Ezypay   Kuala Lumpur    2,300.00
```

I copy it from a PDF file into an MS Excel file.  I would get the text below with double spaces and each line is just pasted into one cell like below.

I tried using text functions `=RIGHT(B73,LEN(B73)-E73+2)` and array `=MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B73&"0123456789"))` etc. The array I got from research but I would still tweak the formula since the month character number changes every month, and the single or double digit day.

The amount is constant at two decimals places, using a comma and dot separator.  Unless there is an installment line e.g. 01/24, this "one of twenty-four" will come before the amount 2,916.25 like `0 1 / 2 4 2 , 9 1 6 . 2 5`

I'm looking to use a VBA solution or function to fix the pasted values.

A u g u s t 1 8 A u g u s t 1 8 P o w e r M a c C e n t e r - G b 3 : 0 1 / 2 4 2 , 9 1 6 . 2 5
A u g u s t 1 8 A u g u s t 1 8 B a l a n c e C o n v e r s i o n : 0 2 / 0 6 4 , 6 7 1 . 3 0
A u g u s t 1 A u g u s t 2 * P h p - A n y t i m e f i t - E z y p a y K u a l a L u m p u r 2 , 3 0 0 . 0 0
A u g u s t 1 3 A u g u s t 1 5 S t a r b u c k s C o n g r e s s Q c 2 7 5 . 0 0

Comment: For problems like this, consider pasting into Word and using Advanced Find/Replace. If needed, wildcard searches can be very powerful. Here's one site describing those: http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Answer (score 1):

this is some test code that imports the content of a pdf file into excel by running it through msWord

```
Sub pdf2excel()

    ' import pdf file text into excel, using msWord as a proxy

    ' set reference to microsoft word object library

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application

    Dim file As String
    file = "C:\statements\statement.pdf"

    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open( _
                    Filename:=file, ConfirmConversions:=False, _
                    ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                    PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
                    WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", _
                    Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:="")

'   wdApp.Visible = false                   ' can make msWord visible if you want ... would help in determining location of data

    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = Range("d2")                   ' put paragraph text in column D

    Dim prgf As Paragraph
    For Each prgf In wdDoc.Paragraphs
        cel = prgf.Range.Text               ' put paragraph into worksheet cell
        Set cel = cel.offset(1)             ' point to next cell down
    Next prgf

    Set cel = Range("b2")                   ' put word text in column D

    Dim wrd As Word.Range
    For Each wrd In wdDoc.Words
        cel = wrd.Text
        Set cel = cel.offset(1)
    Next wrd

    wdDoc.Close False
    Set wdDoc = Nothing

    wdApp.Quit
    Set wdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I did run the code, change the path and enabled Microsoft Word and PDF in the project references library.  I got the 'run-time 1004' error though.  I stepped into the code and it just runs in the For-Next repeatedly.

Comment: make sure that you have a blank worksheet.   it should put values in to the cells

Comment: Is there a solution that could fix the pasted values in MS Excel?