# Extract PDF table and insert into Excel

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, adobe

I have a PDF file that contains a table. I want to use Excel-VBA to search just the first column for an array of values. I have a work around solution at the moment. I converted the PDF to a text file and search it like that. The problem is sometimes these values can be found in multiple columns, and I have no way of telling which one it's in. I ONLY want it if it's in the first column.

When the PDF converts to text, it converts it in a way such that there is an unpredictable amount of lines for each piece of information, so I can't convert it back to a table in an excel sheet based on the number of lines (believe me, I tried). The current method searches each line, and if it sees a match, it checks to see if the two strings are the same length. But like I mentioned earlier, (in a rare case but it does happen) there will be a match in a column that is NOT the column I want to search in. So, I'm wondering, is there a way to extract a single column from a PDF? Or even the entire table as it stands?

```
Public Sub checkNPCClist()

Dim lines As String
Dim linesArr() As String
Dim line As Variant
Dim these As String

lines = Sheet2.Range("F104").Value & ", " & Sheet2.Range("F105").Value & ", " & Sheet2.Range("F106").Value & ", " & Sheet2.Range("F107").Value

linesArr() = Split(lines, ",")
For Each line In linesArr()
    If line <> " " Then
        If matchlinename(CStr(line)) = True Then these = these & Trim(CStr(line)) & ", "
    End If
Next line

If these <> "" Then
    Sheet2.Range("H104").Value = Left(these, Len(these) - 2)
Else: Sheet2.Range("H104").Value = "Nope, none."
End If

End Sub

Function matchlinename(lookfor As String) As Boolean

Dim filename As String
Dim textdata As String
Dim textrow As String
Dim fileno As Integer
Dim temp As String
fileno = FreeFile

filename = "C:\Users\...filepath"

lookfor = Trim(lookfor)

Open filename For Input As #fileno

Do While Not EOF(fileno)
    temp = textrow
    Line Input #fileno, textrow
    If InStr(1, textrow, lookfor, vbTextCompare) Then
        If Len(Trim(textrow)) = Len(lookfor) Then
            Close #fileno
            matchlinename = True
            GoTo endthis
        End If
    End If
    'Debug.Print textdata
Loop

Close #fileno
matchlinename = False
endthis:
End Function
```

Comment: There is no way I know of that allows VBA to access the file structure of a PDF file to extract data like this. It is part of the reason why some folks convert their stuff to PDF's in the first place.  I've tried OCR and online converters without much luck.  This probably doesn't help, but can you get the PDF doc in any other format?  If you do manage to crack it I'd be very interested. https://pdftables.com/pdf-to-excel-vba do a free trial on their converter, it may work for you.

Comment: check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970565/fix-pasted-text-from-pdf-credit-statement